# Solution to the equation $f((1+x)^n-1) = nf(x)$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Fix $n>1$, I want to find power series $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ which satisfies $$ f((1+x)^n -1)= nf(x).$$

I know that the $0$ function and $\ln(1+x)$ satisfy this equation for all $n$.

My question is, if we fix $n$, does there exist more functions which are solutions? If so, can we characterise these functions depending on $n$? If not, can one give a proof that the above solutions are the only solutions for any $n>1$.

Comment: Also $c \ln(1+x)$ for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, if you write $f(x) = a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$ and substitute in to the difference of the two sides of the equation, the coefficients of each power $x^k$ 
are linear combinations of $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ that must be $0$: the coefficient of $x^1$ is $0$, of $x_2$ is $n (n-1) (a_1 + 2 a_2)/2$, etc.  The coefficient of $x^m$ will be a combination of 
$a_1$ to $a_m$, with the coefficient of $a_m$ in this coefficient being
$n^m-n$.  Thus for any $n > 1$, it is possible to solve for $a_2, a_3, \ldots, $ in terms of $a_1$.  We know the solution since $a_1 \ln(1+x)$ satisfies the equation.  Thus all the solutions are $c \log(1+x)$ for arbitrary constant $c$.